# QC Extract sql query from Graph report

Tags: sql, reporting, ota, hp-quality-center

Hi I have a QC Graph report and a QC SQL statement that are meant to produce the same data but the data does not always match. I need to run the SQL once a day and save the results in a database. We trust that the data in the Graph report is correct. Is it possible to generate an SQL statement that is exactly the same as the one being used by a QC graph report.

I know you can create an excel report but my issue here is that I need the exact same query being used by the Graph report as an SQL statement...

Comment: Depending on the database this solution depends on, you can try to log the sql queries run against it and see if you find the one that does what you want, alternatively, if the Excel report is live connected (it can be refreshed from Excel), then the query must be in the Excel file.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I will try the log option because the report is not an excel report but a graph report instead.

I managed to get the query to align with the gaph report but I would still like to know how to extract the query from a graph report.